# Can I get an instance of one of my application running inside another application like the case of Ola App in PhonePe app?

Tags: android

I am trying to integrate one of my application (let's say App A) with an another application (let's say App B) in such a way that I need the App B to open inside App A.

[Pic 1: PhonePe showing a list of applications which could be opened inside it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfdPO.jpg)

[Pic 2: Ola app selected and is opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oARQ.jpg)

Notice that in Pic 2 Ola still is running inside PhonePe application only. How could this be done?

One more caveat is that the App B should be able to respond to incremental changes, i.e any update in the user-experience should reflect onto the App B present inside App A. Shifting of the files of App B under App A directory would not serve the purpose.

As of now, I tried using [Google Instant Apps](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-instant-apps/index.html#0) which opens an application outside the application. 
I read about the concept of [Micro-apps](https://www.entrepreneur.com/article/308583) but there is no code support available to it on the net.

Any help on how this particular thing could be achieved would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use webview. As ola is web app inside phonepe’s webview.